# Check image urls in visual studio asp .net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2017

So I currently have a solution I cloned from bit bucket, but it is full of broken image links and showing a default image.

How would I check which image links the solution is trying to use.
Is the database stored locally.
As I'm new to visual studio I'm really not sure where to check.
Also I'm using nop commerce

It's odd because the images are there in this directory: `/content/images/thumbs/`
But when I try to navigate to that directory in my browser I get this message:

> HTTP Error 403.14 - Forbidden The Web server is configured to not list
>   the contents of this directory.

But when I navigate to the image in the browser it displays: `/content/images/thumbs/0000013.png`

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding this on your web config file then rebuild your project:

```
<system.webServer>
 <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/> 
</system.webServer>
```